# Spring Boot AWS logging level

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, spring-cloud

I have several Spring Boot micro services that connect to Config Server and Eureka.  All are running inside Docker container in ECS. They are very chatty and I would like to eliminate the non-critical messages.

> 2023-01-06 16:42:03.426 WARN 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0]
> c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient : Request execution failed with
> message... 2023-01-06 16:43:28.082 INFO 1 --- [trap-executor-0]
> c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver : Resolving eureka endpoints via
> configuration... 2023-01-06 16:50:03.679 INFO 1 --- [freshExecutor-0]
> o.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec... 2023-01-06 16:42:03.426 INFO
> 1 --- [tbeatExecutor-0] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient...

And each service has its application.properties file with the following:

> logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.http=FATAL
> logging.level.com.netflix.discovery=FATAL
> logging.level.com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws = ERROR
> logging.level.com.netflix.eureka.registry = ERROR
> logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet = FATAL
> logging.level.org.hibernate = ERROR logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari =
> ERROR logging.level.org.apache.tomcat=ERROR
> logging.level.org.apache.catalina=ERROR

But the messages continue to show up in the log files. I don't get why this is, since those messages are INFO and WARN.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disable below error messages use the config below

```
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient=error
```

also in your config I see `logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet = FATAL logging.level.org.hibernate =`  this looks wrong, every line should have one gorup name = something, then new line.

Comment: I think that line that looked wrong was in the SO posting - my application.properties file don't have that.  I added
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient=error
logging.level.com.netflix.discovery.shared.resolver.aws.ConfigClusterResolver=error
and it seems to work on the RetryEurekaHttpClient but not on the ConfigClusterResolver as I still see info logging statements

Comment: can you please share a reproducer ? because that line you shared suppose to stop  ConfigClusterResolver logging also.

Comment: what do you mean reproducer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ah I see - there is no code other than services that try to register with eureka.  This is all handled by Spring so not sure how to best reproduce it other than log entries.

Comment: I still see the logging entries, so not sure what is going on here.  But I appreciate the attempt to help me solve it.

Comment: if you generate a small reproducer I can look into it.